# How can I customize the uninstallation process of Eclipse features?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse provides [a mechanism](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_update_core_installHandlers.html) to customize the installation process of features. What is the counterpart mechanism for customizing the *uninstallation* of features. For example, how can I delete a folder in ".metadata/.plugins" folder when the user uninstalls a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Eclipse 3.4, the mechanism to customize an install/uninstall are called Touchpoints.  See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html for some more information.

But I don't think you can remove something from a workspace on uninstall ... even within one uninstall operation, you're only in that one workspace (and I use the director to install/uninstall, so I'm not near my development workspace at all).

Comment: Won't action `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove` be able to remove a folder inside ".metadata/.plugins"?

Comment: which workspace?  I have 3 created with my current version of eclipse, and if I uninstall something the best case it might hack something out of one of them.

Comment: I see your point. The problem is that Eclipse doesn't know the list of workspaces affected by a particular bundle.